# .net form inside user control loses values after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, viewstate

I have a pretty standard master page with a ContentPlaceHolder.

```
<section class="content" style="height:100%;">
    <form id="contentForm" runat="server">
        <div class="container" style="background:#fff; border:30px solid #fff; height:80%;">
            <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
                <section class="span8" role="main" style="height:100%;">
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="MainContent" runat="server" />
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

Inside that ContentPlaceHolder I have a usercontrol that contains a dropdownlist and a textbox.

With the from tag in the Master page, if I change the dropdown selection, the page submits as expected and the form fields maintain their selected values.  Now, I need to remove the from tag from the Master page as it is causing some other pages to fail.  I want to put the form tag inside the usercontrol.

```
<form id="trackingForm" runat="server">
<div id="employee" class="statsTable"><strong>Employee:</strong> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="selectPerson_DDL" runat="server" Width="200" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="selectPerson_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</form>
```

The page still submits as before but now I lose the selected value in the dropdownlist.  I've tried various options such as checking for Page.IsPostBack, etc.  I see that ViewState exists after the form is submitted.

Why would the control behavior change just because the form tag is now in the usercontrol?

Comment: you can use update panels to avoid postbacks

Comment: I went with a full page postback since there are several controls on the page that are populated based upon that dropdown selection.  Seemed easier at the time.  Now, I may regret it.

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms supports only one FORM element with a runat="server" per page. Is there a reason why you have to use FORM, could you not replace it with a DIV ?

Comment: I can no longer have the form tag in the Master template as it causes other usercontrols to fail.  I am trying to put my form tags only where needed and inside the usercontrol.

Answer (score -1):

putting your form inside an asp:updatepanel control should solve the issue.

Comment: How does this deal with moving the form tag into the usercontrol? My page only works as expected when the form tag is outside the usercontrol.

Comment: Tried that, it does not work.  The form reloads with the default value in the dropdownlist instead of the value I selected.

Comment: have you tried setting AutoPostBack = False for your dropdown control?